# Can Cauchy Integral Formula be applied for curves with interior containing a pole?

Tags: complex-analysis

Referring to the proof in Stein's Princeton Lecture in Analysis for the Cauchy Residue Formula, the Cauchy Integral Formula was used where $$\displaystyle\oint_C \frac{a_{-k}}{(z-z_0)^k} ~ dz = 0$$ where $k\geq 2$ for some boundary circle $C$ of a neighbourhood of $z_0$ implying in the neighbourhood (or should it be deleted neighbourhood and why?) of $z_0 $, $\frac{a_{-k}}{(z-z_0)^k}$ has a primitive.

However $z_0$ is a pole and I thought to apply Cauchy Integral Formula on a curve in a simply connected region we require $f$ to be holomorphic in an open set containing the closure of the simply connected region and a region with a pole is not simply connected? Its somewhat confusing for me so can someone clarify when and why can Cauchy Integral formula be applied? Sorry if I made any elementary mistakes as I am learning complex analysis by myself. Thank you.